# CrawlerRunner not Waiting?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I was trying to use the following function to wait for a crawler to finish and return all results. However, this function always returns immediately when called while the crawler is still running. What am I missing here? Aren't join() supposed to wait?

```
def spider_results():
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)
    runner.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    runner.join()
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordig to scrapy docs ([common practices section](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script))
`CrawlerProcess` class is recommended to use in this cases.